# How can a case fan with a 8pin connector plug into the 4pin fan header on the motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, fan

I recently bought a Delta 12cm case fan online and it has a 8pin connector (but only 7 wires) which I can't plug it into the motherboard. I put a typical 3pin fan connector beside it in the image, so its size can be compared.

[image: Delta PFC1212DE 12CM FAN]
[image: Delta PFC1212DE 12CM FAN 8PIN Connector]

As far as I know, a typical 12cm case fan should have a 3pin or 4pin connector (either the big one or the small one). My motherboard currently has two 4pin fan headers available. I tried to search for 8pin to 4pin cable but couldn't find one. So how can a case fan with a 8pin connector plug into the 4pin fan header on the motherboard?

By the way, I found the specifications [Delta PFC1212DE Fan Specifications](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Delta%20PDFs/PFC1212DE-F00.pdf) for this fan but since I know nothing about electronics I am not sure if it's of any use.

Comment: You bought an incompatible fan, you should go get a properly compatible one.

Comment: I do believe that is a server fan. It is quite different than what is used in a PC.

Comment: The fan require 4 Amps at 12 Volts... as mentioned above, that is probably not compatible with your power supply and/or controller.

Comment: 4 amps! 67dB acoustic noise! it will be noisy like a microwave oven.  Even if it had the proper connector, you do not want to install it in a PC.

Comment: If I really don't want to give up the fan, will cutting off its 8pin connector and then replace it with a 4pin connector work?

Comment: No, the 4 amp draw is huge, like 4x what is probably allowed/expected.

Comment: It requires 4 Amps, so if my motherboard does not supply it with that much. Will it still work but at a lower speed?

Comment: No, it will try to draw 4 amps until something gives out.

Comment: A motor cannot draw more than the supply allows. If you supply less it will work slower. Note that at 20% speed it only draws 0.25a - but really this is a monster! You might be better off replacing the cooling fan in your car with this!! :) The wiring is actually standard as shown in the PDF - cut off the connector and put on a 4-pin matching your mobo socket if you really must do this. Better to buy the right thing though.

Comment: Sure it cannnot draw more than the supply allows, but motherboards power curcuitry and wiring(traces) allows for about 1amp, and certannly could do damage to the motherboard for the fans stuff,  You would never try and put that on a motherboards simple fan connectors ever, and no motherboard manuel would indicate that you should either.   Your talking about slamming a 1amp capable connection with a 4Amp load, there will be no supplying less when there wont be a voltage dip, it would be the current draw that would damage it.

Comment: To avoid damage, I am not going to directly connect it to the motherboard 4 pin fan header. But if the 8pin connector is replaced with a standard molex 4pin connector and then directly plugged into the PSU rather than the motherboard, which allows many more amps, will this way work without any damage? If yes, will the fan speed control (either by voltage / PWM) still work?

Comment: Yes off the PSU for the 12V line and ground line (usually the red and black), and potentially you can get the rpm sensor (often yellow) and the pwm driver (often blue) to work, but the "case" fan positions on most motherboards (although 4 pin), are usually voltage contolled not PWM, usually only the primary CPU and optional cpu fan locations provide a pwm signal.  Always test first with power only, supplied by the PSU, once that is correct, you are unlikely to mess up anything testing the rest.